# Related Rates: Population

Tags: exponential-function

Since January 1, 1960, the population of a city has been described by the formula $P=36000(0.95)^t$, where $P$ is the population of the city $t$ years after the start of 1960. At what rate was the population changing on January $1, 1977$?

How do I calculate the rate of the population change?

Comment: Are you familiar with the derivative of a function? Could you compute $ \frac{dP}{dt} $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $P=36000(0.95)^t$

Now, $\dfrac{dP}{dt}=36000\times\ln(0.95)\times(0.95)^t$

After $t=1977-1960=17$ years,

$$\dfrac{dP}{dt}=\mbox{ rate }=36000\times\ln(0.95)\times(0.95)^{17}\dfrac{\mbox{ people}}{\mbox{ year}}$$